# how to count href with underscore using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i want to check if any link contains underscore or not. i want to count how many hrefs contaning _

```
 MatchCollection links = Regex.Matches(html, "(<a.*?>.*?</a>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
 lbllinks.Text = "links .Count.ToString() + " links on this website ";
```

if string contains like  `<a id="HyperLink1" href="http://www.sample_1.com">HyperLink</a>`

output - 1 underscore link

Comment: Use a HTML parser: For C#, you have several choices: HtmlAgilityPack, CSQuery, AngleSharp... Then use a CSS selector: `a[href*=_]`

Answer (score -2):

i dont see whts the problem if some asking to solve one particular problem with regex.

give the suggestion to use the parser is different thing but down vote. i dont know why..

well u can try the below

https://regex101.com/r/gF7bE8/1

```
<a.*href\s{0,}=\s{0,}".*_.*".*>(.*)<\/a>
```

if any match found mean html contains the '_' in href of a. else does not.

Comment: Maybe because it's a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2729609) to do that. Btw. Your regex doesn't work. Your own sample matches more than the requested link. On the other hand it doesn't work: [see here](http://goo.gl/Z5ShaV) There is no link containing underscores but your regex matches.

Comment: @Verarind oh i see.. hmm right.  thanks to correct me.. and let me know my mistake .. !!